# Redirect not working on React, using react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here, is my full code details:

**route.js**

```
<AdminRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

And, my admin route:

**AdminRoute**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import AdminLayout from '../components/layouts/AdminLayout'

const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            <AdminLayout>
                <Component {...props} />
            </AdminLayout>
        )} />
    )
}

export default AdminRoute
```

and this is the AdminLayout,

and here it is hitting that console.log correctly, but not redirecting.

**AdminLayout**/

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import { isAuthenticated } from '../../utils/auth';

const AdminLayout = ({ children, ...rest }) => {  
    
    const isLoggedIn = isAuthenticated();
    console.log("isLoggedIn >>",isLoggedIn);
    if(!isLoggedIn){

        //ITS HITTING THIS CONSOLE LOG
        //BUT ITS NOT REDIRECTING
        console.log('hit');
        <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: children.props.location },
            }}
        />
    }   

    return (
        <div>{children}</div>
    );

}
```

and this is the helper function to determine either the user is logged in or not.

**Auth.js**

```
export function isAuthenticated(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("_token")){
        return true;
    }
    return;
}

const auth = {
    isAuthenticated,
};

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Redirect` component needs to be *returned* in order to be rendered, and, ultimately, trigger a redirect, i.e.

```
const AdminLayout = ({ children, ...rest }) => {  
    const isLoggedIn = isAuthenticated();
    if (!isLoggedIn){
        return <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: children.props.location },
            }}
        />
    }   
    return (
        <div>{children}</div>
    );
}
```